# how can I record an audio with mp3 format on raspberry pi3 windows iot core os?

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I want to record an audio with my raspberry pi 3 that has windows iot core, I need to record audio in mp3 format, because the server I will send the audio just accept mp3, but raspberry pi3 doesn't support mp3 format encoding and doesn't have its codec,so I have to use other encoding formats such as M4A and it doesn't useful for me,I would notice that in x86 and x64 UWP Programming the mp3 encoding codec is supported I mean if you compile this code on your desktop windows, it will run and work properly.
so what should I do?Is it possible to install codec on windows iot core like what we do on our usual windows or I should use library for mp3 recording? 
here is a part of my sample code that capture an audio file but because I use "MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3" method it throws exception.
here is the supported codec for various system:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/supported-codecs

```
InitCaptureSettings(selected.Id);
await InitMediaCapture();
var storageFile = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.CreateFileAsync("audioOut.mp3", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
audioFileName = storageFile.Name;
MediaEncodingProfile profile = null;
profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(Windows.Media.MediaProperties.AudioEncodingQuality.Auto);
await audioCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(profile, storageFile);
isRecording = true;
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" - do you want to tell us what error you get, which line it fails at, anything else that might help?

Comment: thank you for your reply, I edited my question and added more details.@iakobski

Comment: Read this: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ (I've not actually downvoted your question - yet)

Comment: thank you for your guidance and advice. I will try my best. @iakobski

Answer (score 0):

As the codec listed in the document in your post, mp3 decode format is not supported in Window IoT Core. As far as i know, there is no way to install the mp3 codec in Windows IoT Core. If using mp3 codec, you will get an error as following:

```
No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D5212)
```

A workaround for this issue is, record the audio in aac format in Windows IoT Core,  download the saved file to your desktop, and then transcode audio file. You can use the Windows.Media.Transcoding APIs to [transcode video/audio files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/transcode-media-files) from one format to another, or any other transcode tool.

Comment: your workaround is not practical because I ran window iot on rassperry pi that is a separate device and if I want download every time, the board  catch an audio file, then it will impose more overhead.actually its time-consuming process.
is it possible use some APIs in my UWP program to transcoding to mp3 in board as it catch the audio file?

Comment: You may try to use some libraries to transcode the audio stream to mp3 format, such as [FFmpegInterop](https://github.com/microsoft/FFmpegInterop). BTW, I'm not recommending you to transcode audio on the Raspberry Pi cause it's very CPU-expensive.

Comment: unfortunately most APIs we can use on normal x86 windows, we can't use them on windows IOT that installed on ARM CPU's devices like raspberry pi, this restriction is my serious problem so your mentioned API is not compatible with raspberry pi too. @Michael

Comment: @sepehrmahmoodian, you means the APIs in FFmpegInterop is not compatible with Raspberry Pi? Sorry i did not test the APIs on Raspberry Pi. May i know why you must choose mp3 format?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I have to send the recorded audio to another server, and that server just accept mp3 format so I need to record mp3 or transcoding other formats to mp3.
The APIs in FFmpeglnterop are not compatible with UWP programing.
 @Michael Xu - MSFT

Comment: @sepehrmahmoodian, the workaround is that, you can create a custom service as a bridge, the devices send the audio data to this service, the service transcode and then sent the stream to the server. If there are amount of devices, this workaround may be not suitable.

Comment: For now I have to inevitably use this method but I think its not the only way and probably there is other APIs for encoding mp3 format for UWP programing. @Michael Xu - MSFT

Comment: @sepehrmahmoodian, i have been trying to find the APIs for transcoding the audio format except in namespace Windows.Media.Transcoding. Thanks in advance if you can find the library and share it.

Comment: I will try to find them too.thanks for your endeavor.